# Trigger refresh of columns when refreshing data in fuelux datagrid

Tags: fuelux

Based on a filter we use (show my objects / show objects of all), we would like an optional column to show/hide (if "all objects" is chosen, it should have an additional column indicating what account it belongs to...)

I know we can add the filter, and it is passed along to the data method so I can retrieve the data from the server there, but can we force a column refresh on the grid somehow?

Thanks very much for your assistance and feedback!

Answer (score 0):

Columns are currently set only once, on initialization.  There are a couple of related feature requests on UserVoice, where you can vote and participate in the discussion:

http://fuelux.uservoice.com/forums/181290-general/suggestions/3624683-datagrid-should-be-able-to-hide-show-columns

http://fuelux.uservoice.com/forums/181290-general/suggestions/3964374-provide-a-method-to-re-render-the-datagrid-in-full